# Making a post request to yobit api

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am trying to make a post request to yobit api in UWP platform,this codes are working for other platforms.Here are my codes-

```
public async Task<RootObject> sellLimitCode()
    {
        RootObject track = null;
        try
        {
            string url = "https://yobit.net/tapi/";


            string parameters = "method=Trade&pair=ltc_btc&type=buy&rate=1&amount=1&nonce=" + (int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
            String strMsg = "api secret";
            var uriBytes = encoding.GetBytes(parameters);
            var uriBytes1 = encoding.GetBytes(strMsg);
            string str_alg_name = MacAlgorithmNames.HmacSha512;
            MacAlgorithmProvider obj_mac_prov = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(str_alg_name);
            IBuffer buff_msg = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(uriBytes);
            IBuffer buff_key_material = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(uriBytes1);
            CryptographicKey hmac_key = obj_mac_prov.CreateKey(buff_key_material);
            IBuffer hmac = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmac_key, buff_msg);
            byte[] digest = hmac.ToArray();
            string hashText = byteToString(digest);
            StringBuilder hex1 = new StringBuilder(hashText.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in digest)
            {
                hex1.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            }
            string sign1 = hex1.ToString();
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            httpWebRequest.Headers["Key"] = "api key";
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Sign"] = sign1;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";



            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

        return track;

    }
```

But I am getting Success:0,invalid key,method or nonce.I have tried changing everything.Still not working.

Comment: You're not including the nonce in the headers.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the api key parameter. Did you register as a developer? See the "Trade API" section in their FAQ: https://yobit.net/en/api

Comment: Also, are you sure that using seconds as a nonce value is such a good idea? A nonce value can only be used once, so unless the API you're using doesn't check, you'll only be able to make one API call per second.

Comment: @CKII-I have key and secret,due to security..I have not put that here.

Comment: @john-according to api document nonce is not header..It is a parameter which should be added in parameter list.And I am sure nonce I have tried with datetime.now.ticks ..that does not work either,if you have some suggestion,I will try that as well

Comment: Add it as a header, too. You're using the "parameter list" to create a signature. How can the API validate the signature if it doesn't know what goes into it? Trust me.

Comment: @john-Ok just now I tried adding nonce as a header too,Still same error